# ThemeProvider affecting non wrapped components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI and ThemeProvider to override some styling, however, the overwritten styles are affecting components I have not wrapped in the ThemeProvider tags. Also, I have had to use !important to override some styling, is there a reason it is still using the default styling over my overwritten style without using !important?

My code is below. I just want to overwrite the styling for the dropdown components but the CreateNewFolder component is being affected too.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiOutlinedInput: {
            input: {
                padding: "8px 14px !important"
            }
        },
        MuiInputLabel: {
            formControl: {
                transform: "none !important",
                top: "-6px !important",
                left: "45px !important",
                backgroundColor: "white",
                fontSize: "0.8rem",
                padding: "0 6px"
            }
        },
        MuiSelect: {
            select: {
                "&:focus": {
                    backgroundColor: "white"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```
return (
        <>
            <div
                style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                    padding: "25px 95px 15px 75px",
                    height: "10vh"
                }}
            >
                <div>
                    <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        onClick={handleNewAdunit}
                        style={{ marginRight: "15px" }}
                    >
                        <AddIcon /> &nbsp; Adunit
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={handleFolder} variant="outlined">
                        <AddIcon /> &nbsp; Folder
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <div style={{ display: "flex", paddingLeft: "30px" }}>
                    <SearchBar
                        inputProps={{
                            value: "",
                            onChange: () => {},
                            style: {
                                width: "300px"
                            }
                        }}
                        results={[]}
                        displayKey={"component"}
                    />
                    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                        <Dropdown
                            label="Sort By"
                            variant="outlined"
                            onChange={() => {}}
                            menuItems={[
                                {
                                    label: "Last modified",
                                    key: "last modified"
                                },
                                { label: "Option 2", key: "option 2" },
                                { label: "Option 3", key: "option 3" }
                            ]}
                            style={{
                                width: "150px",
                                marginLeft: "30px"
                            }}
                        />
                        <Dropdown
                            label="Show"
                            variant="outlined"
                            onChange={() => {}}
                            menuItems={[
                                { label: "My files", key: "my files" },
                                { label: "Option 2", key: "option 2" },
                                { label: "Option 3", key: "option 3" }
                            ]}
                            style={{
                                width: "150px",
                                marginLeft: "30px"
                                // height: "35px"
                            }}
                        />
                    </ThemeProvider>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <CreateNewFolder ref={folderRef} />
                <Snackbar
                    ref={adunitRef}
                    variant="info"
                    message="Stay tuned. New feature coming soon!"
                />
            </div>
        </>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but the theme seems to be global. You can access it with the `useTheme` hook, which should mean that the theme can be accessed not only as a prop passed down in the tree, thus the theme being also on a global level. Again, it might be wrong